# Where does concrete5 store form submissions in the database?

Tags: phpmyadmin, concrete5, concrete

I know that it can be found under reports and forms, but I need it from the actual database. Where is it? I'm using phpmyadmin to look for it but I cannot seem to find it

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Core Form block the table for the Block is the btForm, then an Answer Set is created in the btFormAnswerSet, and the values are put into individual records grouped by Answer Set in btFormAnswers.